# if evaluation in vba , vb.net

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

In C or other languages `if` evaluated using short-circuiting evaluation.
But in VB ,VB.Net I see that `if` doesn't stop evaluation after get 100% result.
This code is fine

```
dim str as string
str=""
If Len(str) = 0 Then
    Console.WriteLine("yes")
end if
```

But this gives error,

```
dim str as string
str=""
If Len(str) = 0 Or CInt(str) > 0 Then  'Error System.InvalidCastException:
    Console.WriteLine("yes")
end if
```

Obviously null string doesn't covert to integer .the `if` check `Len(str) = 0` get `true` and should stop but it again evaluate next .
Why it is like this???

But in [Short-Circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) listed vb, vba, vb.net as supported.

**Another example,**

```
dim str as integer
str=10
If str=10 and str="" Then  'Error
    Console.WriteLine("yes")
end if
```

Comment: That's just how VBA works. It was created before short circuiting existed. If you are using VB.NET you can use `AndAlso` or `OrElse` but not in VBA.

Comment: @braX I'm quite certain short-circuiting had existed for many years in the C family of languages at the time VBA was created.  I would sooner think that it was a design decision at the time to avoid multiple "and" and "or" operators, in which case the most general form is the one adopted where they are bitwise operators.

Comment: Are you actually working in VB.Net?  If so, don't use `CInt()`, or any of the methods you're listing above.  Use [Integer.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) instead.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Agreed, if you are checking user input or unknown source but I was influenced by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions#remarks regarding CInt() etc.

Answer (score 0):

> But in Short-Circuit listed vb, vba, vb.net as supported.

I think you misunderstood the source. It lists .NET and VBA but for

- Visual Basic .NET

  - Eager operators: `And`, `Or`
  - Short-circuit operators: `AndAlso`, `OrElse`
- Visual Basic, Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)

  - Eager operators: `And`, `Or`
  - Short-circuit operators: `Select Case`

So it actually says .NET supports short-circuits only for the operators `AndAlso`, `OrElse` and VBA supports short-circuits only for the operator `Select Case`.

But your example is using `And`, `Or` which are listed as eager operators.

---

So this code in VB.NET

```
Dim str As String
str = ""
If Len(str) = 0 Or CInt(str) > 0 Then  'Error System.InvalidCastException:
    Console.WriteLine("yes")
End If
```

Can be rewritten as

```
Dim str As String
str = ""
If Len(str) = 0 OrElse CInt(str) > 0 Then 
    Console.WriteLine("yes")
End If
```

or as nested statment

```
Dim str As String
str = ""
If Not Len(str) = 0 Then
    If CInt(str) > 0 Then 
        Console.WriteLine("yes")
    End If
Else 
    Console.WriteLine("yes")
End If
```

or

```
Dim str As String
str = ""
If Len(str) = 0 Then
    Console.WriteLine("yes")
ElseIf CInt(str) > 0 Then 
    Console.WriteLine("yes")
End If
```

Comment: NO...the same nested statement is
Dim str As String
str = ""
If Not Len(str) = 0 Then
    If CInt(str) > 0 Then  
        Console.WriteLine("yes")
    End If
else
    Console.WriteLine("yes")
end if

Comment: @AyanBhunia you are correct, fixed it. Does this answer your question?